Java 1.8 / SQL Server 2008 R2 : unable to run query when encryption is activated
I'm working in Java 1.8 and with a SQL Server 2008 R2 (I'm fully aware that it's not supported since a long time, but it's unfortunately not in my hand) which only support TLSv1.
I use ms-sql jdbc to connect to the database and retrieve some data via a query. When setting the SQLServerDataSource, there is an option to enable/disable the encryption : setEncrypt(). I tried both modes with the exact same code :

When encryption is disabled, the connection is successful (I can see it on SQL server side via this query : SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_connections with encrypt_option = FALSE) and I'm able to run the query to retrieve data.

When encryption is enabled, the connection is successful (I can see it on SQL server side via this query : SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_connections with encrypt_option = TRUE) but at the executeQuery() step I get this error : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.


I tried several versions of mssql-jdbc : 6.2.2.jre8, 8.2.2.jre8 and 12.8.0.jre8. Same behavior.
I also tried to adjust SSL protocol via JDBC (dataSource.setSSLProtocol("TLSv1")) or via java.security (Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms", ...) and Security.setProperty("jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms", ...)) : no impact.
Any idea what could explain this behavior ? As the encryption is the trigger, I guess it's related to TLS protocol, but I don't understand why it fails only at query execution step.

"which only support TLSv1" this isn't true. The only reason it would be is if you haven't updated your instance since January 2018. That was almost 7 years ago. Perhaps it's not only time to stop using an end of life version of SQL Server, but it's also time to start updating your software that is/was supported.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/tls-1-2-support-microsoft-sql-server

I indeed mean "the instance" only supports TLSv1, not SQL Server 2008 in general. I fully agree that's an upgrade is more than recommended : unfortunately it's not in my hand, and I try to find a solution with the "given" constraints.

But 2008 does support TLS1.2... so the problem is your instance hasn't had any (recent) security updates installed. Install them.. this isn't a programming issue, it's an internal process issue. What, out of interest does PRINT @@VERSION; actually return?

Here is the result if PRINT @@VERSION; : Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64).
Again I can't do anything on the server as it's not managed by me. It's a bit more complicated than a simple patch, as it's part of an application with many dependencies.

RTM?! Why have you never updated your instance?! That's over 14 years of not installing a single security update... Whoever the DBA(s) for your company are should be huge out to dry; that is terrible administration. If you don't manage the instance, and the vendor refused to there is, in truth a simple solution; burn the relationship, and run as fast as you can and never look back. Choose a vendor that actually has some kind of update policy.

Strange, you should get errored out immediately without succeeding to connect if tls was the issue. Are you sure what you seeing is your active connection? perhaps RTM has some bugs in tds though, who knows. Did you try jtds, it has better support for old servers sometimes. You can also run wireshark and compare the protocol chatter between encrypted and not encypted session

I'm not sure why you're getting a delayed error and not on connection, but, anyway, I recreated the setup you're using.
The problem is that server and client must agree on TLS level, and your client wants higher minimal level than what server can dish out.
In java 1.8, at least on my JDK, following TLS version are disabled: TLSv1, TLSv1.1
You can see how it looks if you go to: jdkhome\jre\lib\security\java.security and look for jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms
If you can't bump up TLS (which you should do), what you can do is lessen the minumum TLS level that java can use.
To do this, you should create add own file somewhere in your application which overrides this prop, for example:
sslenable.security
Put something like this there:
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
    include jdk.disabled.namedCurves

and start your application with following JVM arguments:
-Djava.security.properties=sslenable.security

This will create the connection, although I'm getting a warning: "WARNING: TLSv1 was negotiated. Please update server and client to use TLSv1.2 at minimum." which you should do at some point.

Thank you @siggermannen for your help ! I tried to override those properties programmatically :
Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms", "TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2");
Security.setProperty("jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms", "None");
After that, when displaying the properties, I don't see TLSv1 as disabled, but there might be some other constraints I don't see. I'll try with a config file and let you know.

@ThibaultCoudert As far as I'm aware, you must set it at start up, and you cannot override it at runtime.
